# Let's get critical: Jun 2013 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Signal Processing Stack Exchange](http://dsp.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Final Results

- [FFT of sine wave not coming as expected i.e single point](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/8604/fft-of-sine-wave-not-coming-as-expected-i-e-single-point)

  **Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [What are some easy to detect reference mark shapes and corresponding detection methods?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/8821/what-are-some-easy-to-detect-reference-mark-shapes-and-corresponding-detection-m)

  **Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Low pass fir filter with non-unity gain](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/8844/low-pass-fir-filter-with-non-unity-gain)

  **Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Smoothing data by using Kalman filter](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/8903/smoothing-data-by-using-kalman-filter)

  **Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Centering zero frequency for Discrete Fourier Transform](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/9039/centering-zero-frequency-for-discrete-fourier-transform)

  **Net Score: 7** (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Can I control per-pixel contrast in an image?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/9083/can-i-control-per-pixel-contrast-in-an-image)

  **Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Filter order vs number of taps vs number of coefficients](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/8685/filter-order-vs-number-of-taps-vs-number-of-coefficients)

  **Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Interpolated FIR filter](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/8851/interpolated-fir-filter)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [How to determine a very low frequency signal?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/8877/how-to-determine-a-very-low-frequency-signal)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [What is the uHz-rotator algorithm?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/9000/what-is-the-uhz-rotator-algorithm)

  **Net Score: 6** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)